# Finding duplicates via SQL with enumeration of results

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have a simple table like so:

```
Hash    Filename
----    --------
qqq     fileq2   
aaa     filea2
bbb     fileb1
aaa     filea3
qqq     fileq1
aaa     filea1
```

Some hashes appear multiple times for different filenames (eg aaa and qqq) and some appear only once (eg bbb).

I want a query which returns the hash and filename of any hash that has duplicate value(s).  No problem so far.  But I also want the output to include an enumeration value to show the instance number of the duplicate.  So using the above data the result would be:

```
Instance    Hash    Filename
--------    ----    --------
       1    aaa     filea1             // Hash aaa occurs 3 times
       2    aaa     filea2
       3    aaa     filea3
       1    bbb     fileb1             // Hash bbb occurs once
       1    qqq     fileq1             // Hash qqq occurs twice
       2    qqq     fileq2
```

What would this query look like?

Comment: The query will depend on which database you are using, Oracle and SQL Server provide analytic functions; with MySQL you'd need to "roll your own" analytic function.

Comment: It's SQL Server but I was hoping to approach the query in the most general way non database-specific way possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's a sql fiddle with the results:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9d6ca/1

```
select
  (select count(1) from data b where b.hash = a.hash and b.filename <= a.filename) as Instance,
  a.hash,
  a.filename
from data a
order by
  a.hash,
  a.filename
```

Comment: NOTE: This query will also return rows for values of hash that are unique; I thought OP specified that rows that had unique values of hash were not to be returned?

Comment: @spencer7593 approach using row_number() is probably more performant than my answer, might want to try his answer as well.

Comment: +1. @Jeremy Danyow: The correlated subquery in the SELECT list can be performance problem with large sets. In the more general case, where Filename is not guaranteed to be unique, you'd need to add some other discriminator in the predicate in the subquery, in order to guarantee a distinct Instance number for each row with an identical hash. (I spent the time in my answer to eliminate the rows where hash was unique; I see now that wasn't really a requirement. The queries in my answer could be a lot shorter.

Answer (score 2):

With MySQL you could "roll your own" analytic function, making use of MySQL user variables, something like this:

```
         SELECT IF(@prev_hash=s.hash,@i:=@i+1,@i:=1) AS `Instance`
              , @prev_hash := s.hash AS hash
              , h.Filename
           FROM ( SELECT @prev_hash := NULL, @i := NULL ) i
          CROSS
           JOIN ( SELECT d.hash
                    FROM simpletable d
                   GROUP BY d.hash
                  HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
                ) e
           JOIN simpletable s
             ON s.hash = e.hash
          ORDER BY s.hash, s.filename
```

With Oracle, you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function, something like this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.HASH ORDER BY t.FILENAME) AS Instance
     , t.HASH
     , t.FILENAME
  FROM SIMPLETABLE t
  JOIN ( SELECT r.HASH
           FROM SIMPLETABLE r
          GROUP BY r.HASH
         HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
       ) s
    ON s.HASH = t.HASH 
 ORDER BY t.HASH, t.FILENAME
```

I think SQL Server syntax would be identical to Oracle (apart from SQL Server using square brackets around identifiers where Oracle uses double quotes.)